# PHPStorm и xdebug: отладка работает только в index.php

Tags: phpstorm, xdebug

PHPStorm прекрасно ловит брейкпоинты, расстановленные в index.php, останавливается в том же index.php при выставленном "Break at first line", но брейкпоинты в любом другом файле попросту игнорируются. Skipped paths в конфиге пуст. В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как оказалось, для выбранного сервера был задан path mapping только для index.php, поэтому шторм даже не смотрел в остальные файлы и не предлагал задать маппинг, т.к. он уже существует. Проблема решилась путем создания маппинга папки проекта с папкой на сервере.